# Want to open popover on react-google-map

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I am trying to open a pop over when a google map shape is clicked
but i am unable to do that
I have tried this method which i am usually using to open a pop up when a button is clicked
But it is not working
Below is my code

```js
    {polygon !== null &&
    polygon.map((poly, index) => (
    <Popover
       placement="top"
       content={() =>
       content(poly)}
       trigger="click"
       className="crime-marker"
       >
       {" "}
       <Polygon
          ref={(ref) =>
       {
       _polyRef(ref);
       }}
       paths={poly.coord}
       onClick={(value) => console.log(poly)}
       onMouseDown={() => {
       _onMousedown(index);
       }}
       />
    </Popover>
    ))}
```

Can somebody help me with this?